# Need help using json API of a broker with python [Xtb - xStation API]

Tags: python, json, api, sockets, ssl

I am trying to create a gui where I can log in to my XTB account.
The broker has an API:
http://developers.xstore.pro/documentation/#getAllSymbols

I have found a login function someone else wrote on stackoverflow a couple of years ago.
I have divided it for parts where I know what is going on (this is the very, very first time I use json, ssl and socket modules, so I'm kinda white about it all).

```
def xtb_log_in(self):
    self.user_id_xtb = self.xtb_login_entry.get()
    self.password_xtb = self.xtb_password_entry.get()


    ###################################################
    # preparing connection
    host = 'xapi.xtb.com'
    port = 5112
    host = socket.getaddrinfo(host, port)[0][4][0]
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((host, port))
    s = ssl.wrap_socket(s)
    ###################################################

    ###################################################
    # sending command parameters
    parameters = {
        "command": "login",
        "arguments": {
            "userId": self.user_id_xtb,
            "password": self.password_xtb
        }
    }
    packet = json.dumps(parameters, indent=4)
    s.send(packet.encode("UTF-8"))
    ###################################################

    END = b'\n\n'
    response = s.recv(8192)
    if END in response:
        print('Print login: {}'.format(response[:response.find(END)]))

    ###################################################
    # sending command parameters
    parameters = {
        "command": "logout"
    }
    packet = json.dumps(parameters, indent=4)
    s.send(packet.encode("UTF-8"))
    ###################################################

    response = s.recv(8192)
    if END in response:
        print('Print logout: {}'.format(response[:response.find(END)]))
```

Now when I tried to do the same with `getallsymbols` command I think I have failed.
Experimentally I have attached these lines to the function above:

```
parameters = {
    "command": "getAllSymbols"
}
packet = json.dumps(parameters, indent=1)
s.send(packet.encode("UTF-8"))
response = s.recv(8192)
```

But unfortunately it didn't work - I think.
How do I use this and other commands properly and get access to the data they are returning?
I just need a brief explanation of how this things work.
I would be grateful if someone fixed this:

```
parameters = {
    "command": "getAllSymbols"
}
packet = json.dumps(parameters, indent=1)
s.send(packet.encode("UTF-8"))
response = s.recv(8192)
```

And would explain to me what is going on in there.

Comment: Usually `APIs` use `HTTP` protocol - so maybe it will be simpler to use `urllib` or `requests` instead of `socket`. But it seems this API use websockets and Python has also module for this type of connection.

Comment: how do you know it doesn't work? Did you get any error message in code or JSON with information about problem? Show it in question (not in comments)

Comment: @furas not there was no error, however, when I am trying to print it, it prints just blank space, or when I was trying to print the response with the .format command it was just b''.
So I assume it does not work, or that I am not knowing how to handle the output...

Comment: go back to documentation - at the top you see link to [wrappers](http://developers.xstore.pro/api/wrappers/2.5.0) and there is Python library (PL: w documentacji na górze strony jest link `wrappers` i tam jest moduł Pythona)

Comment: I don't have active account on xStation to test it - so I can't help more.

Comment: correction: I tested code from question using `account number` (instead of `login`) and it correctly logged me in and `getAllSymbols` gives me results.

Comment: @furas ok. Nice, So maybe I'm just dumb or sth. 
I do log in with account number also, but how did you handled the results of getAllSymbols? How did you get acces to it?
Could you write the code that worked for you?

Comment: you have to `login`, next run `getAllSymbols` and later `logout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this code with my old account and it works for me.

But it needs `account number` from `xStation`  instead of `login` but password is the same as for login to `xStation`

First it needs to login.

Next it needs to run `getAllSymbols` or other function.

And finally it needs `logout`

---

This code works for me. You have to put your `account number` and `password`

```
import socket
import ssl
import json

###################################################
# preparing connection
host = 'xapi.xtb.com'
port = 5112
host = socket.getaddrinfo(host, port)[0][4][0]
s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host, port))
s = ssl.wrap_socket(s)

END = b'\n\n'
###################################################


###################################################
# sending command parameters
parameters = {
    "command": "login",
    "arguments": {
        "userId":   '19xxxxx',     # account number
        "password": 'xxxxxxxxxx'
    }
}
packet = json.dumps(parameters)
s.send(packet.encode("UTF-8"))

# -------------------------------------------------

response = s.recv(8192)
if END in response:
    print('login:', response[:response.find(END)])
else:
    print('login:', response)

###################################################
# sending command parameters
parameters = {
    "command": "getAllSymbols"
}

packet = json.dumps(parameters)
s.send(packet.encode("UTF-8"))

# -------------------------------------------------

response = s.recv(8192)
if END in response:
    print('getAllSymbols:', response[:response.find(END)])
else:
    print('getAllSymbols:', response)

###################################################
# sending command parameters
parameters = {
    "command": "getSymbol",
    "arguments": {
        "symbol": "EURPLN"
    }
}

# -------------------------------------------------

response = s.recv(8192)
if END in response:
    print('getSymbol:', response[:response.find(END)])
else:
    print('getSymbol:', response)

###################################################
# sending command parameters
parameters = {
    "command": "logout"
}
packet = json.dumps(parameters)
s.send(packet.encode("UTF-8"))

# -------------------------------------------------

response = s.recv(8192)
if END in response:
    print('logout:', response[:response.find(END)])
else:
    print('logout:', response)

###################################################
```

---

**EDIT:**

Code in functions:

```
import socket
import ssl
import json

# --- constants ---

HOST = 'xapi.xtb.com'
PORT = 5112

END = b'\n\n'

# --- functions ---

def send(parameters):
    packet = json.dumps(parameters)
    s.send(packet.encode("UTF-8"))

    response = b''
    
    while True:
        response += s.recv(8192)
        if END in response:
            break
        
    return json.loads(response[:response.find(END)])

def login(user_id, password):
        
    parameters = {
        "command": "login",
        "arguments": {
            "userId":   user_id, 
            "password": password
        }
    }

    return send(parameters)
    
def logout():
        
    parameters = {
        "command": "logout",
    }

    return send(parameters)

def getAllSymbols():

    parameters = {
        "command": "getAllSymbols"
    }

    return send(parameters)

def getSymbol(symbol):
    parameters = {
        "command": "getSymbol",
        "arguments": {
            "symbol": symbol
        }
    }

    return send(parameters)

# --- main ---

#HOST = socket.getaddrinfo(HOST, PORT)[0][4][0]
s = socket.socket()
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s = ssl.wrap_socket(s)

# ---

print('login ...')

response = login('19xxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxx')
if response['status'] is False:
    print('Problem:', response)
    exit()
    
# ---

print('getAllSymbols ...')

response = getAllSymbols()    
if response['status'] is False:
    print('Problem:', response)
    exit()

print('getAllSymbols:', response)
data = response['returnData']
# ... do something with data ...

# ---

print('getSymbol ...')

response = getSymbol("EURPLN")    
if response['status'] is False:
    print('Problem:', response)
    exit()

print('getSymbol:', response)
data = response['returnData']
# ... do something with data ...

# ---

print('logout ...')

logout()

# ---

s.close()
```

---

**BTW:**

In [API documentation](http://developers.xstore.pro/documentation/current) at the top of page you can see [Download wrappers](http://developers.xstore.pro/api/wrappers/2.5.0) where you can get Python module.

Comment: Thank you so much!
Do you know how to make a list for each symbol from 'response' object?
Since there are no indices whatsoever or how could I navigate through getAllSymbols output to append each dictionary to a list.

Comment: Nvm, I got it, response[i] is ascii code, I'll menage that I hope

Comment: `socket` gives string/bytes and you have to convert it back to data using `json.loads()` and later you have list with dictionaries and you can use `for`-loop to get `item` from list and check `item['symbol']`